# Accessing Struct members using memcpy in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure like this :

```
struct x{
int a;
int b;
int c;
}
```

I have an array like this :

```
unsigned char bytes[8];
bytes[0] = 1
bytes[1] = 128
bytes[2] = 0
bytes[3] = 0
bytes[4] = 255
bytes[5] = 255
bytes[6] = 0
bytes[7] = 0
```

I want to copy bytes[0] to bytes[3] in struct element "a", bytes[4] to bytes[6] in struct element "b" and bytes[7] in struct element "c". I have to use memcpy.
How can i do that? Please help.

My Try :

```
struct x test;
memcpy( &test.a, bytes, 4);
memcpy( &test.b, bytes + 4, 3);
memcpy( &test.c, bytes + 7, 1);
```

But it is showing different results every time i run it.

Comment: How are you printing the results?

Comment: printf("value of logic1 = %d\n",Test.a);
        printf("value of logic2 = %d\n",Test.b);
        printf("value of logic3 = %d\n",Test.c);

Comment: For one thing, you're not initializing b & c, then copying fewer than 4 bytes into them, so the other bytes will be undetermined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you don't initialize `test`. So what ends up happening is:

- The fields initially have undefined ("garbage") data
- You only **partially write the fields**

For example when you do `memcpy( &test.b, bytes + 4, 3);` if you have `sizeof(int) == 4` (likely) you end up writing only 3 bytes thus **leaving one byte undefined**.

Try something easy like initializing the object:

```
struct x test = {0};
```

Comment: unfortunately i cannot vote up the answer because of less reputation as i am new to stackoverflow. :( But thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @cnicutar You should accept the answer by clicking on the arrow below the vote up/down.